# Choose target location for force:createRecord event

Tags: lightning, lightning-console

I'm firing force:createRecord event from custom lightning component in lightning service console and it seems to always open a new tab or subtab with the record creation form in it. Is it possible to choose to open this in the same/origin tab or in a modal. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this.

Comment: Generally speaking, if it's not in the docs, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue working in lightning service console. I used workspace api to close the tab before firing the force:createRecord event. This helped me to tackle it. Do check out the code snippet for your reference.

```
<!--in component-->
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>

//in controller
var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
workspaceAPI.isConsoleNavigation().then(function(response) {
   if(response){
      var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
      workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
   }
});
var createAcountContactEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createAcountContactEvent.setParams({
   "entityApiName": "Account",
   "recordTypeId": component.get("v.TypeOfRecord")
});
createAcountContactEvent.fire();
```

Comment: +1. Closing the current tab and allowing `e.force:createRecord` to open in tab. Awesome.