# How to open standard create form of salesforce lightning in a new sub tab

Tags: lightning, create-records, standard

I am firing an event e.force:createRecord to open a standard create form in Salesforce lightning but it opens in a new tab rather than a new sub tab. Is there a way to open it in new subtab?

Comment: you can look into workspace api https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation

Comment: @User6670 I had refered to this space before but all it has is opening a subtab but when we fire e.force:createRecord it always opens a new Tab.

Comment: did you tried this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246955/choose-target-location-for-forcecreaterecord-event